# How to group data based on criteria and fill down values

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I'm trying to group values of below list in a dataframe based on `Style`,`Gender` and `Region` but with
values filled down.

My cuurent attempt gets a dataframe without style and region filled down. Not sure if it is good approach or would better
to manipulate the list `lst`

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [
        ['Tee','Boy','East','12','11.04'],
        ['Golf','Boy','East','12','13'],
        ['Fancy','Boy','East','12','11.96'],
        ['Tee','Girl','East','10','11.27'],
        ['Golf','Girl','East','10','12.12'],
        ['Fancy','Girl','East','10','13.74'],
        ['Tee','Boy','West','11','11.44'],
        ['Golf','Boy','West','11','12.63'],
        ['Fancy','Boy','West','11','12.06'],
        ['Tee','Girl','West','15','13.42'],
        ['Golf','Girl','West','15','11.48']
    ]


df1 = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns = ['Style','Gender','Region','Units','Price'])

df2 = df1.groupby(['Style','Region','Gender']).count()
```

**Current output (content of `df2`)**

[image]

**output I'm looking for**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `reset_index` that will reset back to normal

```
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Is there a way to get the same print of `df1.groupby(...).count()` but without the two columns of the counted elements that appear to the right?  I use `.count()` since I need the unique values for each group.